# React on Rails error exception when prerender is set to true

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'm trying to use the prerender paramter on react on rails components as this :

```
<%= react_component("Welcome", props: @welcome_props, prerender: true) %>
```

but it returns an exception as this:

```
12:56:37 web.1    | ActionView::Template::Error (ERROR in SERVER PRERENDERING
12:56:37 web.1    | Encountered error: "uninitialized constant #<Class:0x000055590018f6d8>::ExecJS"
12:56:37 web.1    | when prerendering Welcome with props: { name: Oussama }
12:56:37 web.1    | 
12:56:37 web.1    | code:
12:56:37 web.1    | 
12:56:37 web.1    |         (function() {
12:56:37 web.1    |           var railsContext = {"railsEnv":"development","inMailer":false,"i18nLocale":"en","i18nDefaultLocale":"en","rorVersion":"11.3.0","rorPro":false,"href":"https://reynhal.local:3000/","location":"/","scheme":"https","host":"reynhal.local","port":3000,"pathname":"/","search":null,"httpAcceptLanguage":"en-US,en;q=0.5","serverSide":true};
12:56:37 web.1    |               ReactOnRails.clearHydratedStores();
12:56:37 web.1    | 
12:56:37 web.1    |           var props = {};
12:56:37 web.1    |           return ReactOnRails.serverRenderReactComponent({
12:56:37 web.1    |             name: 'Welcome',
12:56:37 web.1    |             domNodeId: 'Welcome-react-component-fe389b96-5b9c-4161-af32-0c81ffb2f2bf',
12:56:37 web.1    |             props: props,
12:56:37 web.1    |             trace: true,
12:56:37 web.1    |             railsContext: railsContext
12:56:37 web.1    |           });
12:56:37 web.1    |         })()
```

when I turn the prerender parameter off, it works. 
the component code is this:

```
import PropTypes      from 'prop-types';
import React          from 'react';

export default class Welcome extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    name: PropTypes.string.isRequired, // this is passed from the Rails view
  };

  /**
   * @param props - Comes from your rails view.
   */
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    // How to set initial state in ES6 class syntax
    // https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#adding-local-state-to-a-class
    this.state = { name: 'Hello' };
  }

  updateName = (name) => {
    this.setState({ name });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h3>
          Hello, {this.state.name}!
        </h3>
        <hr />
        <form >
          <label htmlFor="name">
            Say hello to:
          </label>
          <input
            id="name"
            type="text"
            value={this.state.name}
            onChange={(e) => this.updateName(e.target.value)}
          />
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

and the controller code is this:

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  layout "welcome"

  def index
    @welcome_props = {}
  end
end
```

the code is based on default one generated by react_on_rails, the node version is 13.3 and the gemfile of react_on_rails I have is 11.3.0 and the npm version is 6.4.0